# cancel a c# httpClient GetStreamAsync call

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to add the possibility of canceling an http request in an old c# project.

The project uses [HttpClient::GetStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh551738(v=vs.118).aspx) which does not seem to support Cancellation tokens.

Can a GetStreamAsync call be canceled?
What other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2022 Update**: I have left the link to the MSDN article because at the moment I write this the link still works.  However, the link is older and may eventually cease to work, and I noticed the code formatting I saw back in 2017 is no longer there today.  Additionally, based on comments below my answer, I have lightly edited the content of my answer to remove an unhelpful sentence as well as a pointlessly italicized word.

**Original Answer**: I spotted an alternative solution from a MSDN blog post written in 2012.  It might be of some help to you.  The author is using `GetStringAsync` but the principle also applies to `GetStreamAsync`.  Article: [Await HttpClient.GetStringAsync() and cancellation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2012/12/07/await-httpclient-getstringasync-and-cancellation/).

In the MSDN article the author is using `GetAsync(...)` which can take a cancellation parameter.  A simple solution for Nathan's issue could be something like this...

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;

Uri uri = new Uri("some valid web address"); 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken);

// In another thread, you can request a cancellation.
cancellationSource.Cancel();
```

Note that the cancellation is made on the `CancellationTokenSource` object, **not** the `CancellationToken` object.

Comment: This answer would be so much better if you were to quote some of the relevant pieces of the article (depending on the licensing in the article).  Without the details from the article, if this link break, this answer wouldn't provide an answer anymore.

Comment: You missed the part with GetStreamAsync or GetStringAsync  in your example that make it useless. And what do you mean by "Because of how a stream works"?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetWebData(string url, CancellationToken? c = null)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var t = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url), c ?? CancellationToken.None);
        var r = await t;
        return await r.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as Johns answer, just as an extension method:

```
 internal static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public async static Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url), ct);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
    }
```